# files not on path in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I added a module called `Album`. Here are my codes:
**`<AppName>/module/Album/Module.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
         __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }
}
```

**`<AppName>/module/Album/config/module.config.php`**

```
<?php

return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),

 'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]*',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),



     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );
```

Here is my `controller`:

```
<?php 

 namespace Album\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
 {
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }
 }
```

Then I added module name to `config/application/config.php`. Then I refreshed local server and I got the following errors and warnings:

```
Warning: include(/var/www/html/trialone/module/Album/config/module.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/trialone/module/Album/Module.php on line 28  
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/trialone/module/Album/config/module.config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/trialone/module/Album/Module.php on line 28  
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given.' in /var/www/html/trialone/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 342  
Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given. in /var/www/html/trialone/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 342
```

How can I work around it?
App structure:
[image: img]

Comment: Are you sure that you have those files under this path? Maybe you misspelled something? Can you paste here your app structrue?

Comment: i think you forgot to put getAutoloaderConfig function in Module.php